# A way to communicate between applications within linux

Tags: linux, daemon, raspberry-pi

I'm currently in the planning stages and could do with help. I'll be using a rasberry pi with various modules plugged into (i2C, USB etc) it, these could be anything such as modules to measure temp, wind speed, direction etc.

The idea is to have each module run its own daemon, this daemon will feed data to the main program upon request or the main program can request the daemon to restart.

All this will be happening on the raspberry pi, not over any sort of network.

My question is what to use to communicate between the main program and the daemons. I've been reading about using dbus, but there are quite a few saying use it as a last resort.

I've been researching for a while and couldn't come up with any other (perhaps easier) ways.

On a side note, the idea of separating them out is because if any modules has issues i can easily restart it without effected the main program.

Comment: I guess this question is not really limited to the Raspberry Pi. "Standard" ways would include UNIX sockets (see Brendan's answer) or Shared Memory (have a look at this page on the Pi site: [Shared Memory](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/memory/shared-memory)).

Comment: Yeah i agree, it's not really limited to the RPi.

Comment: Another method for slower synchrosization (every x minutes) would be a file - something like a shared database or simply log files for each daemon which are parsed by the main program.

Answer (score 2):

Look into ZeroMQ. It's sockets on steroids.

It's easy to get started with, and it's perfect for communication between threads in the same process, or between different processes. ZMQ takes away a lot of the headaches that multi-threading and process communication usually means.

Simply use `socket.bind` in your "main program", and `socket.connect` in your clients.

In your case it sounds like you might be intereste in the Pub-Sub pattern, where the server subscribes, and clients publish, meaning that it's a one-way communication.

Else, you might be interested in the Req-Router-Dealer-Rep pattern.

http://www.zeromq.org/

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [unix sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).

> The API for Unix domain sockets is similar to that of an Internet socket, but it does not use an underlying network protocol for communication.

I can't link to examples because you didn't give a language, but basically the server will open a socket somewhere on the filesystem (preferably somewhere it has read/write access to, but all other programs only have read access). Then client programs can connect to that socket and send requests just like they would over the internet.

Answer (score -3):

well there is a school of thought that says you should program every job that your application does as a separate, discrete program that does ONLY that one job and then pipe them to each other via the shell or call each of them when needed by your main program.

Just a few programs running in background (gotta love &) killed if needed and ease of polling.

no need to reinvent the wheel, you know.

Comment: He's not asking why/if he should do this, he's asking how.